# Разваливается инфоблок в битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, openserver

работаю на Win10 x64, openserver. Настройки по дефолту стоят такие http - apache_2.4+php_7.0-7.1-x64 
php - 7.0-x64
mysql - mariaDB-10.3x64
битрикс встал нормально, но при редактировании инфоблока из админки, разваливается css, кто ни будь сталкивался с таким? Как лечить ? [image: скрин]

Comment: В консольке есть сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: Сразу не глянул, 113 ошибок висит, все на 403 ссылаются - для примера
/bitrix/admin/iblock_admin.php?type=news&lang=ru&admin=Y:8 GET http://bitrixtest/bitrix/themes/.default/compatible.css?15734714982827 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Тема остается открытой, уже часа 4 воюю не пойму что с ним не так